# Tensorflow: fine tuning a model with additional layers, key not found error

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

So, I have an architecture where let's say I have several layers and let us denote it by Arc1: `A1->A2->A3->A4->Loss1`. I trained this architecture with a loss function: Loss1.

I have a new architecture Arc2: `A1->A2->A3->A4->A5->A6->Loss2`, where A1 to A4 in both layers have same name and A5 and A6 are new layers. I want to train the whole architecture Arc2 slowly with lower learning rate but want to restore the `A1 to A4` from previous trained architecture Arc1. I tried the implementation in tensorflow but I get the error :

```
tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key Arc/new_layers/A5_weights not found in checkpoint
         [[Node: save/RestoreV2_38 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/RestoreV2_38/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_38/shape_and_slices)]]
```

It is true that the weights corresponding to new layers are not in old checkpoint, but as this is a standard technique, what would be a way to do this? As far as I know, freezing a network will not solve this, as I want the gradient to propogate the all the way to A1 (while learning with lower learning rate later).

It is a standard technique to train a new softmax layer, but if you have 2 or more new fully connected layers or other layers, should it be really problematic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are restoring variables using a [`tf.train.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver), you need to specify the variables you want to restore in the constructor ([`__init__`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver#__init__)), otherwise it will default to all variables in the current graph.

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(old_vars)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(new_vars)
    saver.restore(sess, save_path)
```